# 4 legs on weekdays, 2 on weekends

Tags: riddle, wordplay

1. *I have 4 legs on weekdays, but 2 on weekends.*
2. *I can fly, but I have no wings.*
3. *I rhyme with many, but don't rhyme with many.*

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2):

A little out of the box, but I think the answer might be

> Germany

I have 4 legs on weekdays, but 2 on weekends.

> Let's look at the days of the week in German - Monta**g**, Diensta**g**, Mittwoch, Donnersta**g**, Freita**g**, Samsta**g**, Sonnta**g**.
>  Here, we see that the "fall letter" **g** appears four times on weekdays and twice on weekends. I think the legs here refer to the part of the words which fall below the bottom line of primary writing lines.

I can fly, but I have no wings.

> Germany can fly (its flag).

I rhyme with many, but don't rhyme with many.

> Germany rhymes with the word "many", however it does not rhyme with many words (at least, relatively speaking).